# Power BI - Use an unrelated table to find valid combinations of data

Tags: validation, powerbi

I think I can ask this question without any example data:

Let's say I have a large table, maybe 100 columns and a million rows. On each row, there are only a few valid combinations of data, but that only applies to five of the columns. The other 95 columns can really be anything.

I have another validation table of just those five relevant columns, where each row is a valid combination of values. Can I use this to create a "Valid/Invalid" flag on the main table?

I was thinking that we wouldn't be making a relationship between these tables, although, every validation column will also exist in the main table, so I suppose you could? In my real-world case there are no good primary keys, but if the solution is a many-to-many relationship I'll edit the question and title here.

Edit: the above was answered but here's a more difficult variation:
What if rows in the main table don't all include all five validation values? The validation table shows valid combinations, but nulls are allowed in the main table?

Comment: You can use Merge your data table with the validation table in Power Query Editor using those 5 columns as joining key. After merging and expanding information, you can see either NULL of Valid value in new columns. All rows with NULL value can be considered as invalid data.

Comment: Thanks, this absolutely works for what I asked for. I just realized what I actually need is slightly different, so I'm adding an edit to my question. But your comment is very useful, thanks.

Comment: For your new issue, you can create a set of sample data and show here for better understanding.